# Unable to execute animation on hover using CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

I need to show some `<div>` boxes after hovering on the `<div>` with codeyad class (.codeyad).

```css
* {
  direction: rtl;
}

html,
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 19px;
}

div :not(.container, .codeyad) {
  border: 1px solid rgb(59, 59, 59);
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  position: relative;
  left: 120%;
  opacity: 0;
}

div.js {
  transition: left 0.3s 0.2s, opacity 0.3s 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.python {
  transition: all 0.6s 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.php {
  transition: all 0.9s 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

div.codeyad:hover div.js {
  left: 0%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="codeyad">کدیاد</div>
  <div class="js">جاوا اسکریپت</div>
  <div class="python">پایتون</div>
  <div class="php">آموزش php</div>
</div>
```

The problem is with the following part:

```css
div.codeyad:hover div.js{
  left: 0%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I need to show the `<div>` with class `js` by using animations after hovering on the `<div>` with class `codeyad`, but it doesn't execute!
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your selector like below. It will select the class .js only when your hover on div.codeyad. learn about `+` - ([Adjacent sibling combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)).

*It will work until you keep the HTML structure as is. i.e. `.codeyad` is immediately followed by `.js`*

```css
div.codeyad:hover + div.js {
  left: 0%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Working code below (updated with comments)

```css
* {
  direction: rtl;
}

html,
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 19px;
}

div :not(.container, .codeyad) {
  border: 1px solid rgb(59, 59, 59);
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  position: relative;
  left: 120%;
  opacity: 0;
}

div.js {
  transition: left 0.3s 0.2s, opacity 0.3s 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.python {
  transition: all 0.6s 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.php {
  transition: all 0.9s 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

div.codeyad:hover~div.js,
div.codeyad:hover~div.php,
div.codeyad:hover~div.python {
  left: 0%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="codeyad">کدیاد</div>
  <div class="js">جاوا اسکریپت</div>
  <div class="python">پایتون</div>
  <div class="php">آموزش php</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to use `div.php, div.python, div.js` at a time?

Comment: I did not get you, can you please explain?

Comment: I mean, assume that I need to show all the child `<div>`s within the `<div>` with `container class` aftaer hovering on the `<div>` with `codeyad class`. actually showing all the three <div>s brought in the following: ```<div class="js">جاوا اسکریپت</div>
  <div class="python">پایتون</div>
  <div class="php">آموزش php</div>```

Comment: Then you can use `div.codeyad:hover ~ div {
  left: 0%;
  opacity: 1;
}` . This will target all divs inside

Comment: Thanks but I need to choose them one each time, not in totally.

Comment: I mean, I want to use their class name

Comment: I still dont get you then, If you hover codeyad, then you want to show all the divs inside at once?

Comment: Yes I do, but I need to refer to the <div>s by their class name instead of referring to them by only writing `~<div>`, something like :`div.codeyad:hover ~ div.php, div.js, div.python{ ...}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243150/discussion-between-tushar-and-hossein).

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you can achieve this by using this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator

A note to keep in mind when using this: It'll work *"only if it immediately follows the first element, and both are children of the same parent"*

So to get the desired result you would do something like this:

```css
div.codeyad:hover+div.js {
  left: 0%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code (last snippet provided), you are accessing div with class "js", that is a child of div class "codeyad"

You are telling css something like this =>

```
<div class="codeyad"> // on hover, do something with child class js
   <div class="js"></div>
</div>
```

I think the easiest solution is with **javascript**, where you can access hover functions. Or you can also try with CSS, but it is a little tricky, you have to know CSS selectors. Link provided [here.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)